# Unix epoch time converts to human readable incorrectly with PHP

Tags: php, unix, epoch

`1630440104` is the Unix epoch time code example.

This PHP code

```
echo date('Y.m.d', '1630440104').' at '.date('H:m:s', '1630440104');
```

outputs it as `2021.08.31 at 23:08:44` which is incorrect.

Because the correct output should be `2021.08.31 at 23:01:44`.

Whatever time code I insert into the above PHP code it returns 08 minutes instead of the actual value.

Where have I made a mistake?

Comment: Incidentally, you can include the "at" in the format string if you escape it, so you only have to call `date()` once. `echo date('Y.m.d \a\t H:i:s', '1630440104');`

Comment: @Sammitch just because it should in this particular case. Use any online epoch converter with my time code. Timestamp can be any minutes less or more. It is correct only when the actual minutes is 8. Because it always shows 8 minutes, as I've stated in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is using `m` in the second `date` call. `m` is month, minutes is `i`.

```php
echo date('Y.m.d', 1630440104).' at '.date('H:i:s', 1630440104);
```

or

```php
echo date('Y.m.d \a\t H:i:s', 1630440104);
```

Just a side note, `date` second parameter accepts an `int` not a `string` in `declare(strict_types=1);` a TypeError would occur.

You can find the available formats under [`DateTime::format` docs page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php).

Comment: I should detect my mistake myself as there is already `m` in the date part. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No, problem. It happens.